# How to access name of a particular sheet eg. 2nd sheet from a workbook without providing the sheet name using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
    df=pd.ExcelFile("sample.xlsm")
    #Check number of sheets and their name
    if(len(df.sheet_names)==8):
        sheet1=df.parse(0)
        sheet2=df.parse(1)
        sheet3=df.parse(2)
        sheet4=df.parse(3)
        sheet5=df.parse(4)
        sheet6=df.parse(5)
        sheet7=df.parse(6)
        if(sheet1.name=='Work'): pass
        else: print("Throw an error") 
    else: print("Throw an error")
```

I have a workbook saved locally as sample.xlsm and I have to check whether the number of sheets it contains and the sheet names are correct or not. For my case the number of sheets should be equal to 8.
After checking the number of sheets I'm checking whether the sheet names are correct or not but I couldn't find any way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
names=list(df.sheet_names)
if(names[0]=='Work'):pass
```

I have found a way to solve the problem. I can use df.sheet_names and typecast it to a list
and save it in a variable(names here). Then I can easily check sheet name using the list names.